# What Facebook App settings determine whether data is released?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve a list of pages that an authorized Facebook user has access to update through a Facebook App using the PHP SDK.

```
require_once('facebook.php');

$config = array(
  'appId'  => APPID,
  'secret' => SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "select page_id, name from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid = me())",
);

$result = $facebook->api($params);

print_r($result);
```

When we put this FQL into the Graph Explorer in Facebook for testing purposes, it gives us the following (correct) data.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "page_id": 1234567689,
      "name": "A page we have access to"
    },
    {
      "page_id": 987654321,
      "name": "Another page we have access to"
    }
  ]
}
```

When we use the PHP SDK it returns an array with no values. I have verified we have the manage_pages permission in our Application settings. Furthermore, if I simplify the FQL parameters to:

```
    $params = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT name from user where uid = me()",
    );
```

This works in both the Graph Explorer AND the Facebook PHP SDK. This leads me to believe that the problem is some hidden setting in the Application area that is affecting the first FQL query. By the way, when using the Graph Explorer the only permission we needed to successfully return the data was manage_pages and so I don't think it's a permission problem.

Has anyone run into this before or has anyone successfully returned a list of pages that a Facebook user is an administer to? Any ideas on how I could start debugging this? Is there an alternate way to retrieve the information we want in case this is some kind of bug?

Comment: Output the access token your script is using to make the call (`$facebook->getAccessToken()`), and [check whether it _really_ has the permission](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) …

Comment: When I output $facebook->getAccessToken() I receive a string back that is about 70-80 random characters. Is there a way to actually *see* the permissions by deciphering it?

Comment: How about you click on the __link__ that I posted, genius …? ;-)

Comment: Your link text and the default font text are virtually identical on my second monitor. I didn't even realize it was a link. StackOverflow should have more contrast between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'        => 'manage_pages,read_stream',
            'redirect_uri' => RETURN_ADDRESS,
        )
);
```

It turns out when you generate the login request you have the option to set the scope for the application. In our scope we did not have manage_pages set even though the Application did.

Hope this helps -- it cost the better part of the day to realize that what you request and what is offered are managed separately.